# what will happen when two people execute removeLiquidity in uniswap v2?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, uniswapv2

According to the code of `uniswap-v2/v2-periphery/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol` in function `removeLiquidity()`:

```js
    // **** REMOVE LIQUIDITY ****
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) public virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB) {
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).transferFrom(msg.sender, pair, liquidity); // send liquidity to pair
        (uint amount0, uint amount1) = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).burn(to);
        (address token0,) = UniswapV2Library.sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        (amountA, amountB) = tokenA == token0 ? (amount0, amount1) : (amount1, amount0);
        require(amountA >= amountAMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT');
        require(amountB >= amountBMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_B_AMOUNT');
    }
```

***IUniswapV2Pair(pair).transferFrom(msg.sender, pair, liquidity);***

This means the liquidity will first be transferred to the pair contract and then execute the `burn()` function, it is in:

```js
    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function burn(address to) external lock returns (uint amount0, uint amount1) {
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        address _token0 = token0;                                // gas savings
        address _token1 = token1;                                // gas savings
        uint balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        uint liquidity = balanceOf[address(this)];

        bool feeOn = _mintFee(_reserve0, _reserve1);
        uint _totalSupply = totalSupply; // gas savings, must be defined here since totalSupply can update in _mintFee
        amount0 = liquidity.mul(balance0) / _totalSupply; // using balances ensures pro-rata distribution
        amount1 = liquidity.mul(balance1) / _totalSupply; // using balances ensures pro-rata distribution
        require(amount0 > 0 && amount1 > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY_BURNED');
        _burn(address(this), liquidity);
        _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0);
        _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1);
        balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        if (feeOn) kLast = uint(reserve0).mul(reserve1); // reserve0 and reserve1 are up-to-date
        emit Burn(msg.sender, amount0, amount1, to);
    }
```

***uint liquidity = balanceOf[address(this)];***

It means the contract uses the `balanceOf[address(this)]` to calculate how many `token0` and `token1` the user will get. So when two or more people are doing `removeLiquidity` at the same time, will the liquidity be equal for all people?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible `burn()` to be called by more than one time at once, because (1) EVM transactions are sequential and can't be executed concurrently, and (2) the `burn()` method has reentrancy protection, via the `lock` modifier.